# Standard Pitfalls of Web Hosting when Coding?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, host

I got asked a question the other day by friend and it got me thinking. He asked me "What are your biggest struggles when developing new code / software when it comes to the web server?"

At first I didnt know how to answer, I have been coding PHP / MySQL and little Perl for several years now. And why I have my own dedicated server in a data center that I develop them majority of my software on, the script most of the time does not end up living there.

Below are some of the things I can things I take in consideration when developing, just wanted to see if you guys could give me some more things to think about, in which I could take and make a personal check list from as I start to work on new project.

1. What core functionality do I need to accomplish and do I already have a solution to accomplish this?
2. Is the solution part of the standard core of the programming language or will it take a module / plugin to achieve the desired results.
3. Is the module or plugin standard install on most web hosts?
4. Do I know which web host the client is at and their limitations right away?
5. If the module or plugin I need is not standard, can the web host install and secure for me?  If not, am I comfortable installing and securing.
6. Who will be responsible for keeping the module / plugin upto date?
7. How does this effect the over all load on the server?
8. Do I need to re-think the process and look at other solutions / options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not really many problems that can occur with PHP and MySQL when moving them across different servers. As any other interpreter language, PHP will mostly just work anywhere. The problems can mostly appear when:

-different PHP version is installed (and you use latest and greatest features)

-different MySQL version is installed (same as above)

-different PHP configuration or client is unable to change it (ex: short tags)

-if your PHP script works on system level (exec(), perhaps some filesystem operations), a different OS might cause problems